# Android ffmpeg command not working for pitch & tempo change

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to use below command to change pitch & tempo in my existing mp4 file, can anybody help me to correct ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg [-y,-i,/storage/9016-4EF8/abcd video.mp4,-af,asetrate=r=46722.3224612449211671764955071340,-filter_complex,[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a],-map,[v],-map,[a],-vcodec,mpeg4,/storage/emulated/0/cut_video.mp4]
```

Comment: too late but you should post some log to identify what's the problem..

Comment: @VivekThummar Could you please share the command to only change the pitch of audio. Because `asetrate` changes pitch and tempo both at the same time.

Comment: Sorry but i don't have the code right now